# Access data object in Jupyter extension

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've created a JavaScript extension for my Jupyter Notebook that will plot some data for me. Right now I have the data hardcoded within the extension.

**My question**: is there a way to access a data object that exists within the Notebook?

For example, below is some sample code for an extension:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace'
], function(
    Jupyter
) {
  function test_second_extension() {

    var handler = function () {
      console.log(
          'This is the current notebook application instance:',
          Jupyter.notebook
      );
      var data = [{"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 2, "y":12}, {"x": 3, "y": 27}];
      console.log(data);
    };

    var action = {
        icon: 'fa-comment-o', // a font-awesome class used on buttons, etc
        help    : 'Print notebook instance',
        help_index : 'zz',
        handler : handler
    };
    var prefix = 'test_second_extension';
    var action_name = 'show-alert';

    var full_action_name = Jupyter.actions.register(action, action_name, prefix); // returns 'my_extension:show-alert'
    Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([full_action_name]);
  }

  return {
    load_ipython_extension: test_second_extension
  };
});
```

And this is what I have in a Python3 Jupyter cell:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('[{"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 2, "y":12}, {"x": 3, "y": 27}]')
```

Is there a way to access the data object that is created in the Jupyter cell from within the extension, instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html my help you.  It's not explained why you're creating your own JS plotting extension, but you may want to consider Bokeh if you want an interactive JS plotting package.

Comment: Do you mean data from Jupyter be accessed by the browser? Meaning it can also be access in dev console?

Comment: @fcsr - Yes, essentially, data within a Jupyter cell being accessible from the console (and therefore accessible from my javascript extension)

Comment: @Trenton_M - The reason for using our own JS plotting extension is to give us a quick display of common data in a plot that we designed that fits many of our data structures. It's something we have working in Zeppelin currently, but we're attempting to make the switch over to Jupyter. I haven't looked into Bokeh, I'll try to see if that fits my use case. But I'm still curious if there's a way to access the data object from a cell in the javascript extension.

Comment: there seems to be a useful response posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773092/javascript-jupyter-notebook-how-to-get-code-cell-content

Answer (score 1):

A bit janky but try this

```
from IPython.core.display import Javascript
import json

#list of dicts
list_of_dicts = [{"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 2, "y":12}, {"x": 3, "y": 27}]

#convert to json string
json_list = json.dumps(list_of_dicts)

#run in cell
#This will run in the console check your browser
Javascript("""
var json_list = {};
window.variable = json_list;
console.log(json_list);""".format(json_list))

#or as a function
#replace console_log with what you need
def run_in_console(data):
    json_list = json.dumps(data)
    return Javascript("""
        var json_list = {};
        window.variable = json_list;
        console.log(json_list);""".format(json_list))
```